# Trying to import the private key into a PKCS12 format key store, but instead I get usage note

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, server

I am following this tutorial 
http://ankitagarwal.com/wordpress/2014/05/08/https-communication-between-an-android-app-and-tomcat7-using-self-signed-certificates/

and I am currently on "Create the Server’s Key Store containing its Self-Signed Digital Certificate" section.

When I do

openssl pkcs12 –export –inkey web_server_private_key.pem –in web_server_ssl_certificate.pem –out web_server_key_store.p12

I get usage information...why?

No keys are imported/generated.

[image]

Comment: did you copy/paste that command? Those hypens don't look like ascii hyphens, more like em dashes.

Comment: Good eye, @tedder42: `–` != `-`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thx. putting that in as an answer because I realized I can easily test it locally.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your copy/pasted example uses "fancy hyphens". Here's what happens when I run that locally:

```
openssl pkcs12 –export –inkey web_server_private_key.pem –in web_server_ssl_certificate.pem –out web_server_key_store.p12
(prints usage information, as in your screenshot)
```

And with ascii hyphens:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey web_server_private_key.pem -in web_server_ssl_certificate.pem -out web_server_key_store.p12
Error opening input file web_server_ssl_certificate.pem
```

web_server_ssl_certificate.pem: No such file or directory

So, that explains the usage information.